# How to save uncommitted changes to another branch without committing on current branch(no stash or shelve)

Tags: tortoisehg

Im on branch A and I have changes on it that I realize should be on a different branch. I want to update to the other branch without my changes disappearing, yet I dont want those changes to stay on branch A. I want to do this without stash or shelve. Can I just copy the repo changes? Like If I have repo A I can just copy and paste to have Repo B and then when I switch branches I think Repo B remains the same but Repo A changes or is that not right?

Comment: Why don't you want to use those utilities?  They are effectively designed to do what you are describing.  Is there a particular reason you don't want to use those functions?  What do you think copy and pasting will achieve that stash won't?  I'm not trying to be rude, but that's like saying I want to get to point B, but I don't want to walk in a straight line.  There could be legitimate reasons, but I think your question would benefit from some additional details.

Comment: @zero298 Its more like I was told not to due to issues that can arise and that it would be easier to just copy the repo

Comment: Well shelve is how I would have said to do it. But I would use the command line hg shelve, not the (different) shelve built into THG

Comment: I found out by having different repos I can push any changes on them to the remote and pull to the other repo if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this will be to do

`hg update <other branch> --merge`

This will try to update you to the other branch and take your uncommitted changes along. This may result in merge conflicts which you then have to resolve.

Also, I am not sure why you don't want to achieve this using shelve. Using shelve in such cases is completely fine and there should not be any issues. If you want to do it shelve way, it will look like:

`hg shelve`
`hg update <other-branch>`
`hg unshelve`

The `unshelve` step may lead to merge conflicts.